# How to display AlertDialog in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

I am trying to display AlertDialog in one of the methods of the BroadcastReceiver's subclass. My set up is

```
            if(telisinthedatabase == true){
                 String checkid = dbHelp.getidbySimcardnumber(tel);
                 LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(thisclasscontext);
                 View statusupdateView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.statuslayout, null);
                 TextView statustext = (TextView) statusupdateView.findViewById(R.id.statuseditText);
                 String text[] = msg.split("\n");
                 statustext.setText(text[0]+"\n"+text[1]+"\n"+text[2]+"\n"+text[3]);
                 new AlertDialog.Builder(thisclasscontext).setTitle("Current status of the tracker at: "+checkid).setView(statusupdateView)
                 .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                 {                  
                   @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
                   {                    


                   }
                }).show();
            }
```

I copy the instance `context` from the `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` method to `thisclasscontext`.But the program crashed. What is wrong with my coding? I used the same coding at other activities, it was fine.
Thanks

Comment: Give us a log please.

Comment: @Bryan Can you post your error log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot show an alert directly from the BroadCastReceiver because there is no Window of the activity to show a dialog..to show an alert you must start an Activity in the Receiver and in that activity you can show an alert.

Answer (score 1):

Everything mentioned previously is correct. However, if your receiver is the current foreground activity and you reference **its** context, you can raise an AlertDialog - i.e. you shouldn't need to start a new activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can't show a dialog from a Broadcast Receiver.  Only from an Activity and only if that activity is in the foreground or you will get an exception. Without seeing the stack trace it is hard to say, but this is likely your problem.

Comment: Yeah, other people also raise the queries upon this, Broadcast Receiver can't raise AlertDialog.

Comment: I should make transparent activity and from there raise alertdialog